# FFMPEG loop video overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos, one of which is overlaid onto the other.The one that is overlaid is only a few seconds long, and I want it to keep looping whilst the main video plays. Ive tried everything I can think of , but nothing seems to work in ffmpeg

```
 ffmpeg -i mainVideo.MTS -vf " movie=overlaid.wmv  [overlay];[in][overlay] overlay=1000:500 [out]" output.mp4
```

overlays one on top of the other , but with no looping.
Changing `movie=overlaid.wmv` to `movie=overlaid.wmv:loop=0`

gives me an error message

[movie @ 01B19FC0] Key 'loop' not found.
[movie @ 01B19F40] Error parsing options string: 'loop=0'
Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'overlaid.wmv:loop=0'
Error opening filters!

According to the [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#movie), loop is a valid option for movie. Ive tried 0, 1, 10 as the loop value but the result is always the same (an error)

Comment: did you find solution later ?

Answer (score 2):

From [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> Loop over the input stream. Currently it works only for image streams...
>   Repeatedly loop output for formats that support looping such as animated GIF...

I would recommend that you [concatenate](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) the video that you want to loop multiple times and then overlay that video, you can use the -t option to control the duration of your loop